# Difference between if and while break

Tags: c++, performance

Is there a difference between

```
if(x){

   //stuff
}
```

and

```
while(x){

   //stuff
   break;
}
```

?

Is one of them faster?

Comment: Get an introductory book on C++!

Comment: @Nawaz I guess u can't find that in an introductory book

Comment: I doubt anyone is angry. It's just surprising that it didn't occur to you to actually measure it and check for yourself if you're really that interested. Or read some more about C++.

Comment: Why do you bother to optimize things on that low level !?

Comment: @BartoszKP I just learned the word "Assembler". I wasn't able to check it for myself.

Comment: @DieterLücking I don't. It was just interesting.

Comment: @Vider7CC Really? Next time try at least Wikipedia :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets find it out:

```
void Test1() {
    while (GetTickCount()) {
        printf("Hello World Test1");
        break;
    }
}

void Test2() {
    if (GetTickCount()) {
        printf("Hello World Test2");
    }
}

void main() {
    Test1(); Test2();
}
```

Compiled using *VC Nov 2013 CTP* as Release with full optimization:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
012A12A0  /$  FF15 00302A01 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetTickCou ; [KERNEL32.GetTickCount
012A12A6  |.  85C0          TEST EAX,EAX
012A12A8  |.  74 0E         JZ SHORT 012A12B8
012A12AA  |.  68 8C312A01   PUSH OFFSET 012A318C                     ; ASCII "Hello World Test1"
012A12AF  |.  FF15 64302A01 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVCR120.printf>]
012A12B5  |.  83C4 04       ADD ESP,4
012A12B8  |>  FF15 00302A01 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetTickCou ; [KERNEL32.GetTickCount
012A12BE  |.  85C0          TEST EAX,EAX
012A12C0  |.  74 0E         JZ SHORT 012A12D0
012A12C2  |.  68 A0312A01   PUSH OFFSET 012A31A0                     ; ASCII "Hello World Test2"
012A12C7  |.  FF15 64302A01 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVCR120.printf>]
012A12CD  |.  83C4 04       ADD ESP,4
012A12D0  |>  33C0          XOR EAX,EAX
012A12D2  \.  C3            RETN
```

---

As you can see the identical code is generated by the VC compiler. This is although not the case if optimization is disabled:

**Test1**

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00F91630  /$  55            PUSH EBP                                 ; Playground.Test1(void)
00F91631  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
00F91633  |>  FF15 0030F900 /CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetTickCo ; [KERNEL32.GetTickCount
00F91639  |.  85C0          |TEST EAX,EAX
00F9163B  |.  74 12         |JZ SHORT 00F9164F
00F9163D  |.  68 9C31F900   |PUSH OFFSET 00F9319C                    ; ASCII "Hello World Test1"
00F91642  |.  FF15 6430F900 |CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVCR120.printf>]
00F91648  |.  83C4 04       |ADD ESP,4
00F9164B  |.  EB 02         |JMP SHORT 00F9164F
00F9164D  |.^ EB E4         \JMP SHORT 00F91633
00F9164F  |>  5D            POP EBP
00F91650  \.  C3            RETN
```

**Test2**

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump          Command                                  Comments
00F91660  /$  55            PUSH EBP                                 ; Playground.Test2(void)
00F91661  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
00F91663  |.  FF15 0030F900 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&KERNEL32.GetTickCou ; [KERNEL32.GetTickCount
00F91669  |.  85C0          TEST EAX,EAX
00F9166B  |.  74 0E         JZ SHORT 00F9167B
00F9166D  |.  68 B031F900   PUSH OFFSET 00F931B0                     ; ASCII "Hello World Test2"
00F91672  |.  FF15 6430F900 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVCR120.printf>]
00F91678  |.  83C4 04       ADD ESP,4
00F9167B  |>  5D            POP EBP
00F9167C  \.  C3            RETN
```

As you can clearly see they are slightly different:

- If the condition is not met, they behave exactly the same (and thus execute with the same speed)
- If the condition is met, in `Test1` we have to perform one more jump (`00F9164B` - `JMP SHORT 00F9164F`)

=> `Test2` is theoretically faster if the code is compiled without optimizatzion, because the compiler outputs a real loop for `Test1`.

---

Is this premature optimization? **Definitely!**

Answer (score 8):

Logically they are the same. The compiler will probably write out the same code.

You should concentrate on clarity of code rather than contemplating writing obfuscated code in the faint hope that it might be faster.

Answer (score 2):

Output the code in assembler and see if it is the same with your compiler (more likely than not your compiler will optimize both to the same machine code as they are logically equivalent). Almost always it's more important to write readable and maintainable code than to worry about details such as this. With modern compilers being able to optimize out simple cases like this there's very little reason to do anything other than write out code in the most readable manner, in this case I think writing the code as an `if` statement signals your intentions to other readers of your code far better than the `while`+`break` combination.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same. though in theory  the while() add one more `jmp` than the if

Comment: Why so? Where is this extra jump?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan After the `break`, if the compiler is not optimizing it's still need to jump to the condition. Though it will be never executed because of the `break`

Comment: The compiler only writes it out if it is rubbish. And if you care about performance, why would you use a rubbish compiler that doesn't do optimisations?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just checked it with VS2012 - the extra `jmp` is there (in Debug configuration).

Answer (score 1):

```
while(x){

   //stuff
   break;
}
```

The code above seems unreasonable if you're only going to perform an operation once for a given condition. That's why if statements are preferable in this case! As for speed differences, I really doubt any significant advantages of one over the other. Using a while loop in place of an if statement is horrible:

```
if(condition)
{
    // do stuff 
}
else if(another_condition)
{
    // do stuff 
}
else
{
    // do stuff 
}
```

And here's the equivalent using a while loop:

```
while(condition)
{
    // do stuff
    break;
}
while(!condition && another_condition)
{
    // do stuff
    break;
}
while(!condition && !another_condition)
{
    // do stuff
    break;
}
```

Do your team a favor and make your code readable :-)

Answer (score 1):

They have simply different purposes.

`if`  is a selection statement

`while`  is an iteration statement.

And they should be used accordingly to their purposes.

Comment: The question context suggests that it's asking about the difference in terms of performance, not in general.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop functions as an if statement if you break the while loop on first iteration.

but you should never use a while loop for that purpose, because its purpose is looping.

Answer (score -1):

And hence the following will probably give the same, since the for is modified into a while by the C-preprocessor. What other people say about clarity, though...

```
for(;x;){
  //stuff
  break;
}
```

Comment: if you are not answering the question, then please make it a comment. Thanks.